# Finding standrad deviation $\sigma$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, proof-verification

> Carton of milk  can be reserved fresh for $20$ days in average, $\frac13$ from the milk cartons can reserved fresh for $22$ days or more.
>
> Let's assume that the period of fresh is exponential distribued
>
> Find the standard deviation $\sigma$.

My attempt:

$$\begin{align}X\sim \exp(\lambda),&&E[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}=20 \text{ days}\\ \Longrightarrow \lambda=\frac1{20}&&Var[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=400\\ \Longrightarrow \sigma =\sqrt{400}=\boxed{20}\end{align}$$

*Is it correct?*

Comment: did you check that $1/3$ of the cartons can be reserved fresh for $22+$ days?

Comment: no , I did not checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it is (practically) correct. From the other side:

$P(X\ge 22)=1-P(X<22)=e^{-22\lambda}=1/3\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\lambda}=E(X)=\frac{22}{\ln 3}=20.025\ldots\doteq 20$

$\Rightarrow \sigma = E(X)\doteq20$